# Rails update the stock value of a product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model Payment and and a controller name payments_controller. The schema of the Payment model is like as

```
class CreatePayments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :payments do |t|
        t.belongs_to :user
        t.decimal :ammount, :precision => 8, :scale => 2, null: false
        t.decimal :balance, :precision => 8, :scale => 2, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I can add entries to the database but what i want to do is every time a user adds payments the balance field should update with the sum of previous balance and new amount. I don't know how to do it. please help me.

I am some little change in the controller code. Before I was attempting to update the balance in Payment model but now I am trying to update the balance in User model. Still error.

```
user = current_user
netamt =  (amount.to_f - ((amount.to_f*2.9)/100 + 0.30))
payment = user.payments.create(:ammount => netamt)
user.update_attribute(balance: user.balance + netamt)
```

Comment: It's just addition right? What is the problem you can just do `balance += payment_amount`

Comment: Still confused. Suppose user A has $ 60 as a balance in the db field. And if he adds $30 again, the amount field should have $30 and the balance field should have $30 + $60 total $90.

Comment: Yes you can do like this: `amount  = new_amount` and then `balance += amount`

Comment: If it is not your case please post your controller code..

Comment: Why is the balance in the payments model? 

My advice: don't use callbacks, they will cause troubles later on and when testing. Make it a method that wraps both database operations in a transactions.

Comment: Do you have any example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a balance in a payment is not good idea. I think you can store a balance in user model. In this case your code would be like this:

```
begin
  Payment.create(amount: 100, user: user)
  user.update_attribute(:balance, user.balance + 100)
rescue
 #handle a error
end
```

If You want to use your case, You can try next:

```
balances = Payment.where(user: user).order(:created_at)
if balances.any?
  Payment.create(user: user, amount: amount, balance: balances.last.balance + amount)
end
```

Comment: I followed you, update the controller code. Please see my question above. Still getting error like wrong agument

Comment: Got the error _wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)_ for the code **user.update_attribute(balance: (user.balance + netamt))**

Comment: I am very sorry, I have error in my post - update_attributes expect two arguments like this **user.update_attributes(:balance, new_balance)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that in your `Payment Model`. First, give `balance` and `amount` a default value of 0.0 by running a migration to effect the change. You can then do something like this in the model:

```
def update_balance
  self.balance += self.amount
end
```

Then you can add above this method a callback say:

```
before_create :update_balance
```

I guess this should help.

Comment: i got the following error. undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Yes @SantoshAryal. The default values should be for both `payment` and `amount`. If any of them is `nil` at first, the operation is impossible. Did you run a migration to do so?

Comment: Try `after_save` callback.

Answer (score 0):

> I can add entries to the database but what i want to do is every time a user adds payments the balance field should update with the sum of previous balance and new amount. I don't know how to do it. please help me.

You can do it using [Active Record Callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object). Do a callback using your model that if someone add payments call `after_save your_method` and do stuffs you want (in your case you must update the field).

```
after_save :update_payment_amount

def update_payment_amount
  // do stuffs here
end
```